# Celery tasks status: Error: No nodes replied within time constraint

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

I have a project that uses Celery.
Celery worker is not receiving tasks which needs to be processed.
So we checked the status of the worker by running inspect status command.

```
celery.control.inspect().active()
```

But it didn't return anything.None of the inspect commands returned anything. Does this mean we don't have workers at all. We have checked few other questions (https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1087) which addressed the same issue but we don't have any issues related to the versions as some of those answers have described.

Comment: Does `celery.control.inspect().stats()` show anything?

Comment: Nope. none of inspect() commands were working.

Comment: Anything of interest in the celery logs?

Comment: And a silly question: did it ever work?